How many times you did something
I'd like to ask what you think about these sentences.
1 He is likely to be performing 4 times this afternoon
2 He could be performing 4 times this afternoon
My teacher says that we don't use continuous forms with specified number of times something was done. Do you agree? Do I have to then change  " to be performing" to just "to perform"?


We usually write smaller numbers (often below 11) as words ('four times'). 2. Your teacher is wrong. 3. Your sentences are OK.


@MichaelHarvey what about "I have been performing three times this week" is it different and if so why?

My instinct is to say "I have been performing this week" but "I performed three times this week". I think it's because the bare past tense points to a specific number, and the continuous tense reflects that I was in "performance mode" throughout the week. But as Michael says, if your teacher is offering that as a fixed rule it's not helpful.

You aren't using continuous forms about 'specified number of times something was done'; you're using continuous forms about 'specified number of times something will be, or might be, done (in the future)'. I might be performing five times this week if Olivier is sick until Friday; I performed twice last week because he had a hangover and an argument with Vivien.

Though there's technically nothing wrong with your sentences grammar-wise, it would simplify the sentence to say "He is likely to perform...", and that would also make it sound better in some cases.
I'd say your teacher is wrong, but maybe they just want to teach you to sound better. I personally don't see a reason to use "be performing" if "perform" would work as well, but you can say it however you want.
